# How to solve error 'RelatedManager' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, pagination

I have the following view

```
class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentsSerializer
    permission_classes = [CustomPermissionClass]
    pagination_class = MyLimitOffsetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        review = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        return post.comment_set

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        review = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, post=post)
```

My Custom pagination:

```
class MyLimitOffsetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 1
    max_limit = 10
```

Getting the following error:

```
'RelatedManager' object is not subscriptable. Exception location: paginate_queryset
```

If I delete the pagination_class everything is okay. Can't figure out why the code does not working with pagination. Because of comments depend on posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post.comment_set` is *not* a `QuerySet`, it is the manager of a `QuerySet`, you need to call [**`.all()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all) to access the queryset with all the `Comment`s:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    review = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
    #             call .all() ↓
    return post.comment_set.all()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!